# jetty embedded web.xml welcome-file not work

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

```xml
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

```java
Server server = new Server(port);
WebAppContext webApp = new WebAppContext();

webApp.setParentLoaderPriority(true);
webApp.setThrowUnavailableOnStartupException(true);
String webapp = classLoader.getResource(".") + "../../" + resourceBase;
webApp.setDescriptor(webapp + "WEB-INF/web.xml");
webApp.setContextPath(contextPath);
webApp.setResourceBase(webapp);
webApp.setInitParameter("org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Default.dirAllowed", "false");
webApp.setInitParameter("org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Default.useFileMappedBuffer", "false");

server.setHandler(webApp);
try {
  server.start();
  server.join();
} catch (Exception e) {
  logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

```
16-09-06 18:04:56.116 [qtp973576304-16] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - RESPONSE for / h=true
404 null
Date: Tue, 06 Sep 2016 10:04:56 GMT
Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
Content-Type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `../../`

```
File webappDir = new File(new File(classLoader.getResource(".").toURI()).getParentFile().getParentFile().getCanonicalFile().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + resourceBase);
```